# What is wrong with my insert function for min-heaps?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, heap, min-heap

I'm trying to write a minimum heap data structure in C, but I ran into some issues while implementing the `insert` function.

It looks like this :

```
void insert(MinHeap* minh , int key)
{
    if(minh->itemcount == minh->maxSize)
    { 
        printf("cant insert,heap is full\n");
        return;
    }
    minh->itemcount++;
    minh->HeapArray[minh->itemcount]=key;
    int parent=getParent(minh->itemcount);
    while(parent != 0 && minh->HeapArray[parent] > minh->HeapArray[minh->itemcount])
    {
        swap(&(minh->HeapArray[parent]), &(minh->HeapArray[minh->itemcount]));
        parent = parent/2;
    }
}
```

Now the insertion process works if I insert the following values:

```
insert(minheap,5);
insert(minheap,3);
insert(minheap,2);
insert(minheap,4);
```

The output came out to be:

```
2 4 3 5
```

This is a valid output, since it follows the minimum heap property.

But once I start adding more values like 1, the output is:

```
2 1 3 5 4
```

As can you see, there is "bubbling up" of 1 occurring, but it doesn't seem to go all the way up, since 1 should be the first element, not 2.
I'm not sure why is this occurring, because my code for insertion has the same logic as any other minimum heap insertion function.

It would be great if anyone can help with clearing this up.

Some side notes:

`MinHeap` is a type-defined structure, and its members are :

```
typedef struct Heap
{
    int* HeapArray;
    int maxSize;
    int itemcount;
} MinHeap;
```

I have a created an "instance" (with `malloc`) of this structure in the `main` function. I also dynamically allocated memory for the `HeapArray` Member. I also set the `itemcount` member to be equal to 0.

Also, the indexing for my minimum heap array starts with 1 not 0,
so the `getParent` function returns the following:

```
int getParent(int index)
{
    return floor(index/2);
}
```

Comment: Anyway, the problem is your choice of elements to swap. You need to swap the parent with its child, not with some fixed ultimate descendant.

Comment: Ditch the resistance to embrace zero-based indexing. Its a natural part of the language, and every effort to avoid it only creates problems; not solutions.

Comment: *"and sorry for any indentation issues."*: sorry would be meaningful if you would fix it. Why don't you?

Comment: @rici am I not already doing that already? What should I change ?

Comment: @trincot I'm still learning how to indent code properly, sorry.

Comment: I edited the question for you, fixing the indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you are always swapping with the same element, i.e. with the last one at `minh->HeapArray[minh->itemcount]`: in the first iteration of the loop this is indeed the child of `parent`, but if there are more iterations, it no longer represents the child.

As a side issue: you have `parent = parent / 2` in your loop: why didn't you use the `getParent` function here?

Secondly, the `getParent` function does not need to use `floor`: the division is already an *integer* division.

Here is the correction of where the main issue occurred:

```
    int child = ++minh->itemcount;
    minh->HeapArray[child] = key;
    int parent = getParent(child);
    while (parent != 0 && minh->HeapArray[parent] > minh->HeapArray[child]) {
        swap(&(minh->HeapArray[parent]) , &(minh->HeapArray[child]));
        child = parent;
        parent = getParent(child);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I realize my mistake now, also i edited my post with hopefully better indentation, so I hope it's now atleast a bit more readable.